# PHP - imacecreatefrombmp()?

Tags: php, image-processing, bmp

does anybody knows some clean sollution to open image resource from bmp images in PHP?

Comment: Isn't `imagecreatefromwbmp` what you need ? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromwbmp.php

Comment: WBMP images are Wireless Bitmaps, not Windows Bitmaps. WBMP is used for bandwidth constrained, black and white, limited devices such as PDAs and Cell Phones.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Well, to answer your question: it appears it's not built-in, but here's a class that's supposed to do it: http://de77.com/php/read-and-write-bmp-in-php-imagecreatefrombmp-imagebmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google question, before asking it here...

http://www.phpro.org/examples/Convert-BMP-to-JPG.html

http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/3033-there-bmp-support-gd

http://www.corecoding.com/bmp-gd-php-support_c37.html

Comment: I did. This links does not contain clean sollution. Thats why iam asking here.

Comment: Define "clean sollution". Any workaround (as PHP does not provide direct BMP support, AFAIK it's owner is Microsoft) won't be "clean".

Comment: imagecreatefrombmp(). I hoped PHP does offer much more native sollution. Many thanks for your very good answer anyway.

Comment: Just adapt those workarounds, create cleaner code, if you wish. :)

Comment: Ill check it out in next 24 hours THX!